# Ansible Copy Template to different directory with different value

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

I am creating an Ansible role. There is a task that will launch 2 docker container. There is a `docker-compose.yml.j2` file. And the `docker-compose.yml.j2` file will be copied in 2 different directories. When the `docker-compose.yml.j2` is copied to 2 different directory, the docker service name from the compose file will be changed depending on which directory the `docker-compose.yml.j2` file is being copied. And here I got stuck -

- variables -

```yaml
chain_name: ['goerli', 'ropsten']
ropsten _directory: '$HOME/goerli-chain-stack'
goerli_directory: '$HOME/ropsten-chain-stack'
```

- task(snippet)

```yaml
- name: Copy Docker Compose file to goerli & ropsten directory
  template: 
    src: docker-compose.yml.j2
    dest: "{{ item }}/docker-compose.yml"
  with_items:
    - "{{ goerli_directory }}"
    - "{{ ropsten_directory }}"
```

- template

```yaml
version: '2.0'
services:
  {% if {{ goerli_directory }} %} goerli: {% else {{ ropsten _directory }} %} ropsten: {% endif %}:
    image: {{ parity_version }}    
    restart: always
    command:
      --config /parity/config/parity.toml
    volumes:
      - ./config:/parity/config:ro
      - ./chain-data:/home/parity/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```

When the `docker-compose.yml.j2` file is copied to folder `goerli_directory`, the `chain_name` would be `goerli` and same for `ropsten_directory`, the `chain_name` would be `ropsten`.

- `{% if {{ goerli_directory }} %} goerli: {% else {{ ropsten _directory }} %} ropsten: {% endif %}:` - ***this is not working, getting template error*** . It is just an idea, to make.

How can I make like this -

```yaml
version: '2.0'
services:
    goerli: # or ropsten
    image: {{ parity_version }}    
    restart: always
    command:
      --config /parity/config/parity.toml
    volumes:
      - ./config:/parity/config:ro
      - ./chain-data:/home/parity/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go by

```yaml
version: '2.0'
services:
    {% if item == goerli_directory %}goerli{% else %}ropsten{% endif %}:
    image: {{ parity_version }}    
    restart: always
    command:
      --config /parity/config/parity.toml
    volumes:
      - ./config:/parity/config:ro
      - ./chain-data:/home/parity/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```

Because the variable `item`, which is the item you are currently looping on, is accessible in your template and would be equal the content of to those `goerli_directory` and `ropsten_directory` variables since they are processed in your `with_items`.

---

Of even use the more elegant Jinja [inline if expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if-expression):

```yaml
version: '2.0'
services:
    {{ 'goerli' if item == goerli_directory else 'ropsten' }}:
    image: {{ parity_version }}    
    restart: always
    command:
      --config /parity/config/parity.toml
    volumes:
      - ./config:/parity/config:ro
      - ./chain-data:/home/parity/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```

---

And if you want to make use of the `chain_name` variable, then use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html):

The task will become:

```yaml
- name: Copy Docker Compose file to goerli & ropsten directory
  template: 
    src: docker-compose.yml.j2
    dest: "{{ lookup('vars', item ~ '_directory') }}/docker-compose.yml"
  loop: "{{ chain_name }}"
```

And the *docker-compose* template is simplified and goes by:

```yaml
version: '2.0'
services:
    {{ item }}:
    image: {{ parity_version }}    
    restart: always
    command:
      --config /parity/config/parity.toml
    volumes:
      - ./config:/parity/config:ro
      - ./chain-data:/home/parity/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```